# Subclass insists on calling a template rather than constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, copy-constructor

The following does not compile with g++ 4.4.7, with --std==c++0x passed on the command line:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    T v;

    A() { std::cout << "A default constructor\n"; }
    A(const A& i): v(i.v) { std::cout << "A copy constructor\n"; }
    A(A&& i): v(std::move(i.v)) { std::cout << "A move constructor\n"; }
#if 1 // turn this off to fix the version without static_cast
    template <typename V>
    explicit A(const V& i): v(i) {}
#endif
};

class B: public A<int>
{
public:
    B() { std::cout << "B default constructor\n"; }
#if 1 // turn this off to get static_cast that makes it compile
    B(const B& i): A<int>(i) {
        std::cout << "B copy constructor\n"; }
    B(B&& i): A<int>(std::move(i)) {
        std::cout << "B move constructor\n"; }
#else
    B(const B& i): A<int>(static_cast<const A<int> &>(i)) {
        std::cout << "B copy constructor\n"; }
    B(B&& i): A<int>(std::move(static_cast<A<int> &&>(i))) {
        std::cout << "B move constructor\n"; }
#endif
};

B foo() {
    B t;
    return t;
}

int main() {
    B t(foo());
    B t2(std::move(t));
    std::cout << "Result is " << t2.v << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Produces the following error, where it seems the copy and move constructors call the explicit A template rather than the obvious copy/move constructors of A:

```
container.cpp: In constructor ‘A<T>::A(const V&) [with V = B, T = int]’:
container.cpp:26:   instantiated from here
container.cpp:17: error: cannot convert ‘const B’ to ‘int’ in initialization
```

Turning off the first `#if 1` removes the template and this compiles and produces the expected calls. Turning off the second `#if 1` also makes it work (however doing the equivalent in our code would be painful and require vast amounts of careful editing).

Currently I work around this by changing the template constructor to this and adding the bool to all users, but that is ugly:

```
A(const V&i, bool dummy): v(i) {}
```

Questions:

1. Is this a bug in GCC?
2. If not, can somebody explain why this is happening?
3. What is the suggested fix? Are my static_casts correct?

Comment: Not sure as to why the downvote … but we have this unwritten rule here that **downvoters should comment**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> where it seems the copy and move constructors call the explicit A template rather than the obvious copy/move constructors of A:

There’s nothing obvious about calling the `A(A const&)` constructor: you’re calling the `A` constructor with an argument of type `B const&`, and the best match for this is simply the template (which is an *exact* match) rather than `A(A const&)`, which is *not* an exact match (it requires an implicit upcast).

So this behaviour is exactly as expected. If you don’t want this, change the template so that it’s disabled when called with a subclass of `A` (via SFINAE):

```
template <typename V>
explicit A(const V& i,
           typename std::enable_if<! std::is_base_of<A, V>::value>::type* = nullptr)
    : v(i) {}
```

(untested!)

Comment: Indeed your std::enable_if seems to work. It makes it compile, and I also tested that it still allows A<int>(1) to compile. I had to change the nullptr to 0 however.

Comment: I still expected SFINAE to make it act as though A<int>(B) did not exist and thus find the constructor the same way it does if the template is not there at all.

Comment: @user3080602: SFINAE only discards declarations from consideration during overload resolution.  But from the declaration alone, the template constructor is valid and selected.  A problem instantiating its definition is not a substitution failure.